# Entropy without thermodynamic limit

Tags: statistical-mechanics, spin-statistics

I am reading K. Huang Statistical Mechanics (2Ed , Wiley, 1987) Chapter 14 Ising Model. The paragraph of title *Absence of Spontaneous Magnetization in One Dimension* bothers me.

Problem discussed is as follows. One dimensional chain of classical spins each denoted by $s_i$. Each spin can only take values 1 and -1. Energy of configuration is given by
$$
E(s) = -\epsilon\sum_{i=1}^{N-1} s_i s_{i+1} 
$$
where $\epsilon$ is a positive constant and $N$ is number of spins in the system.

The argument presented in the book considers the following transition:

- initially all spins are aligned in the same direction $\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow$

> the energy is at the absolute minimum, but the entropy is zero.

- final state have a wall $\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow\downarrow\downarrow\downarrow\downarrow$

> the energy increases by $2\epsilon$, but the entropy increases by $k \log (N-1)$, since we have $N-1$ choices to place the wall.

Clearly, the author uses the microcanonical ensemble, where $S = k \log \Gamma$ with $\Gamma$ denoting the number of configurations which are characterized by the same value of energy ($-(N-1)\epsilon$ for the initial state and $-(N-3)\epsilon$ for the final state).

The thing that bothers me is why the author does not take the thermodynamic limit in the expression for entropy, a procedure which was introduced and justified in the earlier chapters.

In the introductory chapters the entropy was defined as a function which value can be obtained by the following procedure
$$
s = k\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{N} \log(N-1),
$$
where $s$ denotes the entropy concentration $s=\frac{S}{N}$ and its equal to zero in the considered case.

Can you please explain to how to obtain the author's value of entropy and preserve the thermodynamic limit?

Answer (score 2):

The thermodynamic limit in this case is sort of trivial.  Kerson is assuming that the reader notices that as $N\rightarrow\infty$, the entropy of a single domain wall grows unboudedly, while the the energy of the domain wall remains a (small) constant.  Therefore, the free energy $A=E-TS$ is going to be dominated by the $-TS$ entropic term at thermodynamically large $N$, unless $T=0$.  Since the free energy change associated with creating a domain wall is negative, the domain wall will form spontaneously; the lowest-energy state (with all the spins aligned) is not the equilibrium state.